# how to process checked checkbox with array name?(jquery)

Tags: jquery

i have a checkbox array name "skills[]" and i want add a text to side of clicked(checked) checkbox(whithout Submit)
my code like this:

```
<li><input name="skills[]" class="skills" value="1" type="checkbox" /></li>
<li><input name="skills[]" class="skills" value="2" type="checkbox" /></li>
```

wutdo?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input.skills').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $(this).parents('li').append('<span class="text">your text</span>');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('li').find('.text').remove();   
    }
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V3TZn/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V3TZn/5/)

```
 $("input[name='skills[]']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $(this).parents('li').append('<span class="text">your text</span>');
    } 
    else {
    $(this).parents('li').find('.text').remove();   
    }
});
```